# A method named '/parties/insert' is already defined angular-meteor tutorials

Tags: angularjs, meteor, typescript

I am new to meteor + angular and i am learning this from http://www.angular-meteor.com/

When i reach 3-way data binding section and create folder called collections in socially folder and create file called parties.ts it is giving me error i write following two lines in that file.

```
import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';
export let Parties = new Mongo.Collection('parties');
```

here is the error log.

```
C:\<user>\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.2_4\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:245
                    throw(ex);
                          ^
Error: A method named '/parties/insert' is already defined
    at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1548:15
    at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:113:1)
    at Server.methods (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1544:7)
    at packages/allow-deny/allow-deny.js:191:24
    at [object Object].CollectionPrototype._defineMutationMethods (packages/allow-deny/allow-deny.js:190:5)
    at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:226:8)
    at meteorInstall.collections.parties.js (collections/parties.ts:2:22)
    at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:141:1)
    at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:75:1)
    at collections/parties.ts:2:54
Exited with code: 8
Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

I hope i will get help from this community. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using webstorm and type script ?

Comment: Yes, i am using type script. And using intelliJ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and successfully fixed it. I was also using Atom with the Atom TypeScript plugin, which was automatically compiling the TypeScript files to JavaScript separate from Meteor and creating unnecessary files.

Here are the steps that I took to fix the problem:

1. Check your tsconfig.json file and make sure it has these lines (add or change them if necessary):

   "buildOnSave": false,
   "compileOnSave": false,
2. Close and restart Atom to make sure the Atom TypeScript plugin uses the new settings and stops automatically compiling TypeScript to JavaScript on save.
3. Delete all *.js and *.map files in your "client", "server", and "both" directories.
4. Stop your Meteor instance if it is currently running (probably "ctrl-c" or "command-c", depending on your OS).
5. Run "meteor reset" on the command line.
6. Run "meteor" on the command line to recompile your TypeScript files and restart Meteor.

After that, everything worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Problem could be sometime type script might not be compiled properly into js. Try deleting js file in that folder , edit your typescript file and save. Next recompilation should remove this error.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I move to angular 1 for now. But i am sure you answer will help someone. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error. Did you ever figure it out?

I ended up solving my issue and I had to add "compileOnSave": false" to my tsconfig file. I'm using Atom and it was automatically compiling.

Comment: Not yet, but i move to angular 1 for now, that error comes when i was learning meteor with angular 2 as angular 2 using typescripts so not sure where i am doing wrong. So i move to angular 1 and its working fine there.